# jquery Click To EDIT improving suggestion needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Example what I get this from one of my previous post .I am trying to upgrade this with my need but I failing . I guess it's because of my lack of knowledge in jquery and JavaScripts . But I need this badly .

[Here is Live demo in js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzKWD/8/)

**What I have now:**

There you can see I have a button . If I click the button it will open a Div with Editable input , where I can rename the input and save . you can create many div by clicking the button and rename as you want . Also you can Click the texts again to change the name whenever you want .

**What I am trying to do**

What I was trying to Do is that ,I added a "EDIT" text there .

**What I am mainly trying is** .. if  I Create a DIV  and try to rename again ,without Clicking the text to bring Edit mode . I would like to click EDIT text to bring the Edit mode . Clicking name Should not bring any Edit mode .

I am not finding any way to do that . May be because of my lacking of knowledge . If there is any solution or way it will be Excellent .

My code :

**HTML**

```
<button id="createDiv">Start</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #createDiv, #results span { cursor: pointer; }
   #results div {
    background: #FFA;
    border: 1px solid;
   width:auto;
}
#results input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}
.clickToCancleIcon{
float: right;

}

.new-folder{
height:30px; 
float:left;

 }
```

**JS**

```
    //  Call for document .onload event
       $(function() {
       //  Normal Click event asignement, same as $("#createDiv").click(function
       $("#createDiv").on("click", function(e) {
         //  Simply creating the elements one by one to remove confusion
          var newDiv = $("<div />", { class: "new-folder" }),  //  Notice, each child variable is   appended to parent

            newInp = $("<input />", { name: "inpTitle[]",style:"display:block ;float:left; border:solid 1px #fa9a34", type: "text", value: "Unnamed Group", class: "title-inp" }).appendTo(newDiv),

            newSpan = $("<span />", { id: "myInstance2",style:"display:none; float:left;", text: "Unnamed Group", class: "title-span" }).appendTo(newDiv),


            clickToCancle = $("<a />", { text: "X", class: "clickToCancleIcon" }).appendTo(newDiv),
           clickToEdit = $("<span />", { text: "Edit" , style:"float:right; margin:0px 5px;" ,



             class: "clickToEdit" }).appendTo(newDiv);


        //  Everything created and seated, let's append this new div to it's parent
        $("#results").append(newDiv);
    });

    //  the following use the ".delegate" side of .on
    //  This means that ALL future created elements with the same classname, 
    //    inside the same parent will have this same event function added
    $("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .title-span", function(e) {
        //  This hides our span as it was clicked on and shows our trick input, 
        //    also places focus on input
        $(this).hide().prev().show().focus();
    });
    $("#results").on("blur", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  tells the browser, when user clicks away from input, hide input and show span
        //    also replaces text in span with new text in input
        $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
    });
    //  The following sures we get the same functionality from blur on Enter key being pressed
    $("#results").on("keyup", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  Here we grab the key code for the "Enter" key
        var eKey = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (eKey == 13) { // if enter key was pressed then hide input, show span, replace text
            $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
 $("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .title-span", function(e) {
        $(this).hide().prev().show().focus();
 });
```

for this

```
$("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .clickToEdit", function(e) {
        $(this).parent().children(".title-span").hide().prev("input").show().focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qzKWD/9/